# how to insert a .json document to mongo server by mongojs in node

Tags: json, node.js, fs, mongojs

I'm new with nodeJS and MongoDB.
I have this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('monitor', ["configurations"]);

fs.readFile('json/object1.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);

    db.configurations.insert(data, function(err, doc) {
        console.log(data);
    if(err) throw err;
  });
});
```

no data insered to the mongodb, and I've got no error.
the both console.log(data) print the json string as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to parse it as JSON before inserting it into the document

```
fs.readFile('json/object1.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    db.configurations.insert(json, function(err, doc) {
        console.log(data);
        if(err) throw err;
    });
});
```